# Why the EX4300 continue the system halting?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

Why the EX4300 continue the system halting?

In the LCD, I press to the system halt, then it last this `HALTING` status a very long time.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

so far, there take 20+ minutes at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because once the system is halted, the LCD daemon will detach and the LCD will continue to show the last thing that was on the screen.

Also Halt in Junos does not power off the switch, but merely shut down the routing-engine.

If you attach an ethernet device to the switch, you should see that it does not get link any more - this is a good indication that the switch is halted and can be powered off

Comment: now i can pull out the battery socket. right?

Comment: yes you can - another way to check is that I'm pretty sure the MST LED will be off, which for a stand-alone switch would normally be solid